# SharePoint CSOM: load FileSystemObjectType property from GetChanges()

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I use Web.GetChanges() to retrieve a number of changes from a SharePoint web.

I need to loop through the changes and, for each change that is a ChangeItem, check the **FileSystemObjectType** property (to distinguish between changes to items and changes to folders).

I cannot find a way to load that property:

I cannot load it when I call the GetChanges() because FileSystemObjectType is a property of ChangeItem, not Change    (returned from GetChanges);

I cannot use it once I cast the Change to ChangeItem because it returns a "Property no initialised" exception.

This is the piece of code in question:

```
ChangeCollection changes = spcn.RootWeb.NativeWeb.GetChanges(query);

/* I cannot include FileSystemObjectType here */
spcn.RootWeb.NativeWeb.Context.Load(changes); //, c => c.Include(o => o.FileSystemObjectType));
spcn.RootWeb.NativeWeb.Context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Change change in changes)
{
    Console.Write($"{change.GetType().Name} {change.ChangeType} {change.Time} "); 

    if (change is ChangeItem)
    {
        ChangeItem ci = (ChangeItem)change;

        /* FileSystemObjectType is *not* initalised here */ 
        Console.WriteLine($"{ci.ItemId} {ci.FileSystemObjectType}");
    }
```

I hope that is clear enough, let me know if it isn't (NativeWeb is the SharePoint Web).

Any ideas how I can get that property loaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At least two options could be considered here:

**Option 1**

explicitly specify to load *only* `ChangeItem` via [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ChangeQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958822(v=office.12).aspx):

```
var changeQuery = new ChangeQuery(false,true);
changeQuery.Item = true; //only load change item changes
```

and then request to load `ChangeItem` specific properties like this:

```
  ctx.Load(changes, cc => cc.Include(c => ((ChangeItem)c).FileSystemObjectType));
```

Example

```
var changeQuery = new ChangeQuery(false,true);
changeQuery.Item = true; //only load change item changes
var changes = ctx.Web.GetChanges(changeQuery);
ctx.Load(changes, cc => cc.Include(c => c.ChangeType, c => ((ChangeItem)c).FileSystemObjectType));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var change in changes)
{
     ChangeItem changeItem = change as ChangeItem;
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",changeItem.ChangeType,changeItem.FileSystemObjectType);
}
```

**Option 2**

Lets say you are loading all the changes beforehand like this:

```
var changeQuery = new ChangeQuery(true,true);
var changes = ctx.Web.GetChanges(changeQuery);
ctx.Load(changes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then a specific properties of `ChangeItem` object could be requested with extra query like this:

```
var changeItems = changes.OfType<ChangeItem>();
var changeItemsResult = ctx.LoadQuery(changeItems.Include(c =>c.ChangeType, c => c.FileSystemObjectType));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var changeItem in changeItemsResult)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",changeItem.ChangeType,changeItem.FileSystemObjectType);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vladim, option two is an interesting approach. Both options require two calls to ExecuteQuery (which is what I was hoping to avoid) so I think in terms of performance they are equals?

While I am here, do you know whether there is any way to retrieve changes only for selected lists, but still in one single call?